# Asp.net control to HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm just trying to get the equivalent HTML code that represent a specific control in asp.
for example i have the following label in ASP

```
Label x=new Label();
x.ID="a123";
x.Text="b123";
```

i just want to find a way to get

```
"<span id='a123'>b123</span>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this method to render controls to html.

```
public string RenderControl(Control ctrl)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And use

```
Label x = new Label();
x.ID = "a123";
x.Text = "b123";

var html = RenderControl(x);
```

will give you `<span id="a123">b123</span>`

Comment: If this answer helps you, click green tick on left side of answer to make question is answered.